# If f'(x) exists and is continuous on (p,q) and f'(u) > 0 for u in (p,q), then there is an h>0 such that f(x) is strictly increasing on [u-h, u+h]

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that if $f'(x)$ exists and is continuous on $(p, q)$, and for $u \in (p,q),$ if $f ′(u) > 0$, then there is some $h > 0$ such that $f(x)$ is strictly
increasing on the interval $[u − h, u + h]$

What I have is:

Suppose $f(x)$ was not strictly increasing on $[u-h, u+h] \in (p,q)$. Then for some $m < n \in [u-h, u+h]$, $\dfrac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m} \leq 0$.

$f$ is continuous and differentiable in this interval because it is a subset of $(p,q)$. Applying the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists r \in (m,n)$ such that $f'(r) = \dfrac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m} \leq 0.$

But $f'(r) > 0$ in the neighbourhood of $[u-h, u+h].$ Then by contradiction, we conclude that $f(x)$ must be strictly increasing. $(*)$

However I don't know how/if this proves the existence of such an $h$? Or even why there is an $h > 0$ that implies $f(x)$ is increasing on $[u-h,u+h]$. I feel like the last line $(*)$ is what the question is asking me to prove. I really don't know how to prove the existence of such an $h$. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is basically correct, though if you want to prove it by contradiction, you want to suppose there is NO such $h>0$ such that the statement is correct. (i.e. every $h>0$ fails the statement)

So what you want to say is that:

> For any $h > 0$, f is not strictly increasing on whole $[u-h,u+h]$.

But you can actually prove this directly: by the continuity of $f'(x)$, there is, by the epsilon-delta definition of limit, a $h_0>0$ such that $f'(x) > 0$ always hold on $[u-h_0, u+h_0]$, and hence it is strictly increasing on $[u-h_0, u+h_0]$. The last part follows by your proof(using MVT).